# error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type through `...`

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, type-traits, stdtuple

I have a class `unit`, which has the properties

```
std::is_trivial<unit>::value; // true
std::is_trivially_copyable<unit>::value; // true (on compilers which have this trait)
```

I'd like to pass are vectors of `unit` as a tuple, e.g.

```
using geodeticTuple = std::tuple<unit, unit, unit>;
```

I need these vectors to be passable into conversion functions who use different types of arguments, e.g.

`someOtherType convert(const geodeticTuple& point, const geodeticTuple&  origin)` or

`someOtherType convert(const geodeticTuple& point, ...)`

using MSVC2015, this works totally fine, but with gcc-4.9.3, I'm getting the error:

> error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type `const geodeticTuple {aka const struct std::tuple<unit, unit, unit>}` through `...`

and since gcc-4.9.3 doesn't support the `is_trivially_xxx` style type-traits, I'm having trouble understanding why this is failing.

Is a tuple of trivial types not trivially copyable?

Comment: why are you using an old style c vararg function instead of a variadic function template?

Comment: I was having trouble because it didn't seem to like when there were no arguments present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tuple`'s copy/move assignment operators require special handling for reference types, so they must be user-provided in the general case.

Since the standard doesn't require trivial copyability, it's a QoI issue whether the implementers go to the extra length of providing that guarantee (which would require adding additional specializations).