# Why can't std::tuple<int> be trivially copyable?

Tags: c++, tuples, template-meta-programming

Built with [this online compiler](http://ideone.com/8IGJmd), the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable<std::tuple<int>>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable<std::pair<int, int>>::value << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::is_trivial<std::tuple<int>>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_trivial<std::pair<int, int>>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
0
0
0
0
```

I'm getting the same results with Visual Studio 2015.

Why is that the case? Is there a valid reason an `std::tuple` of POD types, let alone a simple `std::pair`, couldn't be trivially copyable? I presume their implementations provide some custom assignment operators, but how would they be different from the default versions generated by the compiler?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625317/error-cannot-pass-objects-of-non-trivially-copyable-type-through implies that the standard doesn't require it, so implementations don't bother

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The thing that trips `pair` up as far as trivial copyability is concerned is that the standard does not *require* that the copy/move assignment operators be trivial. The standard explicitly declares that the copy/move *constructors* are defaulted, but not so for the assignments. An implementation could default them as well, but the standard does not require it.

There's no really good reason why the standard doesn't require it. But it doesn't.

For `tuple`, things are a *lot* more complicated. Many `tuple` implementations are based on having a storage buffer of the right size/alignment, and using placement `new` to construct the individual members within that buffer. That's all fine and good, but such a type has to implement a manual copy/move constructor, since it must call the copy/move constructor of each type. Even if it knew that they were all trivially copyable and copied them via `memcpy`, that's still a manual operation. And that disqualifies it from trivial copyability.

Now, there are implementations of `tuple` which could be trivially copyable if the types are trivially copyable. But there is no requirement to implement them that way. And it would complicate `tuple` implementations tremendously to do require them to implement themselves one way if all the types are trivially copyable, and implement them in a different way otherwise.

Comment: tuple( const tuple& other ) = default;
 (12)  (since C++11)
tuple( tuple&& other ) = default;
 (13)  (since C++11)

Comment: @user877329: ... so? If the tuple is implemented through base classes of some sort, that can work. But many tuple implementations work by creating a buffer within the tuple and explicitly constructing the elements within it. You can't `default` your copy/move constructors/assignment in those cases.

Comment: How do you deal with constexpr then? Especially before C++20.

Comment: @user877329: Whether something can be `constexpr` has nothing to do with trivial copyability. C++14 made `tuple` `constexpr`-capable.

Comment: I thought about your mentioning of placement new stuff.

Comment: @user877329: Standard library implementations are not limited to what you can do. They could have had some constexpr-style `construct_at` that worked within their system. Or their compile-time `tuple` used a completely different implementation from the non-compile-time one. My point is that there are many ways of implementing `tuple`, and some of them are incompatible with trivial copyability.

Answer (score 6):

Because `std::tuple` has copy/move ctor and assignment operators, it makes the class not-trivially-copyable.

See [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable):

> A trivially copyable class is a class that
>
> ```
> Has no non-trivial copy constructors (this also requires no virtual functions or virtual bases)
> Has no non-trivial move constructors
> Has no non-trivial copy assignment operators
> Has no non-trivial move assignment operators
> Has a trivial destructor
> ```

But `std::tuple` has all of the above constructors and assignment operators.

Comment: The answer is not complete without proving that tuple's special member functions are non-trivial.

Comment: By defining [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)'s copy/move ctors/assignments, it already means such ctors/operators are not trivial.