# Which type trait would indicate that type is memcpy assignable? (tuple, pair)

Tags: c++, c++11, variable-assignment, memcpy, type-traits

I would like to know what type introspection I can do to detect types that assignable by simply raw memory copy?

For example, as far I understand, built-in types tuples of built-in types and tuple of such tuples, would fall in this category.
The motivation is that I want to transport raw bytes if possible.

```
T t1(...); // not necessarely default constructible 
T t2(...);

t1 = t2; // should be equivalent to std::memcpy(&t1, &t2, sizeof(T));
// t1 is now an (independent) copy of the value of t2, for example each can go out of scope independently
```

**What `type_trait` or *combination* of `type_traits` could tell at compile time if assignment can be (in principle) replaced by `memcpy`?**

I tried what would work for the types I would guess should fullfil this condition and to my surprise the only one that fit the behavior is not `std::is_trivially_assignable` but `std::trivially_destructible`.
It makes sense to some level, but I am confused why some other options do not work with the expected cases.

I understand that there may not be a bullet proof method because one can always write a class that effectively is memcopyable, that cannot be "detected" as memcopyable, but I am looking for one that works for the simple intuitive cases.

```
#include<type_traits>
template<class T> using trait = 
    std::is_trivially_destructible
//  std::is_trivial
//  std::is_trivially_copy_assignable
//  std::is_trivially_copyable // // std::tuple<double, double> is not trivially copyable!!!
//  std::is_trivially_default_constructible
//  std::is_trivially_default_constructible
//  std::is_trivially_constructible
//  std::is_pod // std::tuple<double, double> is not pod!!!
//  std::is_standard_layout
//  std::is_aggregate
//  std::has_unique_object_representations
    <T>
;

int main(){
    static_assert((trait<double>{}), "");
    static_assert((trait<std::tuple<double, double>>{}), "");
    static_assert((not trait<std::tuple<double, std::vector<double>>>{}), "");
    static_assert((not trait<std::vector<double>>{}), "");
}
```

---

Of course my conviction that tuple should be memcopyable is not based on the standard but based on common sense and practice. That is, because this is generally ok:

```
std::tuple<double, std::tuple<char, int> > t1 = {5.1, {'c', 8}};
std::tuple<double, std::tuple<char, int> > t2;
t2 = t1;
std::tuple<double, std::tuple<char, int> > t3;
std::memcpy(&t3, &t1, sizeof(t1));
assert(t3 == t2);
```

---

As a proof of principle, I implemented this. <s>I added a couple of conditions related to the size to avoid some possible misleading specialization of `std::tuple`</s>.

```
template<class T> 
struct is_memcopyable 
: std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_trivially_copyable<T>{}>{};

template<class T, class... Ts> 
struct is_memcopyable<std::tuple<T, Ts...>> : 
    std::integral_constant<bool, 
        is_memcopyable<T>{} and is_memcopyable<std::tuple<Ts...>>{}
    >
{};

template<class T1, class T2> 
struct is_memcopyable<std::pair<T1, T2>> : 
    std::integral_constant<bool, 
        is_memcopyable<T1>{} and is_memcopyable<T2>{}
    >
{};
```

This is a very limited workaround because a class like:

```
struct A{ std::tuple<double, double> t; };
```

will still unfortunately be reported as non trivially copyable and non memcopyable.

Comment: Not that this answers your question but it need not be just one single type_trait.  Perhaps write your own that is a combination of traits.  e.g. (is_pod<T>::value || is_trivially_assignable<T>::value)

Comment: @Joe, yes, I asked for a combination of traits as well. I couldn't find one, I tried some. To my surprise `std::tuple<double, double>` is not a `pod` nor `trivially_assignable`.

Comment: In that case, what is the source of your belief that tuple should be trivially assignable?  This answer seems to say not:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779985/why-cant-stdtupleint-be-trivially-copyable

Comment: @Joe Good point. Tuples of memcopyable stuff should be memcopyable, that is my starting point. Either tuple or the traits should be implemented in such a way that this can be detected.

Comment: I understand your starting point, I just don't understand what is the basis of it.  Does the standard say that they should?

Comment: Yes, I am not basing this on the standard but in common sense, see the added code in my question. These answers are helping me understand that this is not required by the standard and I have to add some assumptions in order to exploit the non-explicit memcopyability of tuples. It is a pity none of the traits captures this common sense property of tuples.

Comment: This is a very interesting question - why no upvotes?

Comment: You could create your own type trait with as many specializations for std or library or user defined types as you'd like, with a fallback to something from std type_traits that might be acceptible even though it would have false negatives.  (A comment, because this isn't an answer.)

Comment: @davidbak people upvote less these days. I have a bunch of interesting questions (I am biased) with zero or just one vote.

Comment: @Joe you beat me to posting that link...

Comment: @davidbak, I created a custom trait, added in the last edit of the question.

Comment: I would think that the problem is that assigment operator of `std::pair` is not defaulted... so maybe you should suggest a fix to the standard... Meaningwhile, I would try to not depend on UB even though it would probably works as expected.

Comment: @Phil1970: Existing discussions show that the designers are already aware of this.  The assignment operator can't be defaulted for all pairs without breaking CopyAssignable pair-of-reference types, which are useful and used somewhat widely.  So it would need specialization-linked-defaulting and that has backward compatibility costs too (although it doesn't break existing code, it does break ABI on some implementations).  So it looks like the discussion will continue to weigh pros and cons.

Comment: @BenVoigt, now I wonder why the default "copy assignment" wouldn't just do the operation "=" on member references. Is that an exception to a defaulted copy? (It wouldn't be a copy of course, but it would work transparently and recursively).

Comment: @alfC: Types with non-static reference members default the assignment operators to deleted.  Pair assigns the target objects of its members, not the references themselves (since there is no such thing as reference re-assignment) but this behavior is non-default.

Comment: @BenVoigt right, this is perhaps where the problem starts. It seems that this was a well intentioned heroic but misleading attempt to put semantics over syntax but at the end it doesn't help much.

Comment: @alfC: Well, it's actually there to support the `std::tie` pattern for multiple return values.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16516315/103167

Comment: @BenVoigt, yes, I know, support for `std::tie` is good. What I am saying is that the implementation of `std::pair` has to fight against the language to force the application of `operator=` on the reference members. In other words, `std::pair` is complicated because the language put a restriction that in insight was not very good.

Comment: @alfC: I don't agree.  It's not a restriction, it's a choice to not default to questionable and surprising behavior.  The language allows you to go both ways, you just have to specify.  IMO defaulting to deletion is far better than opting you in by default to a copy assignment that yields a substantially different result than copy construction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct test is in fact `std::is_trivially_copyable`, which allows use of `memcpy` for both making a new object and modifying an existing one.

Although you may be surprised that these return false for types where your intuition tells you that `memcpy` ought to be ok, they are not lying; the Standard indeed makes `memcpy` undefined behavior in these cases.

---

In the particular case of `std::pair`, we can get some insight into what goes wrong:

```
int main()
{
    typedef std::pair<double,double> P;
    std::cout << "\nTC:  " << std::is_trivially_copyable<P>::value;
    std::cout << "\nTCC: " << std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<P>::value;
    std::cout << "\nTCv: " << std::is_trivially_constructible<P, const P&>::value;
    std::cout << "\n CC: " << std::is_copy_constructible<P>::value;
    std::cout << "\n MC: " << std::is_move_constructible<P>::value;
    std::cout << "\nTCA: " << std::is_trivially_copy_assignable<P>::value;
    std::cout << "\nTCvA:" << std::is_trivially_assignable<P, const P&>::value;
    std::cout << "\n CA: " << std::is_copy_assignable<P>::value;
    std::cout << "\n MA: " << std::is_move_assignable<P>::value;
    std::cout << "\nTD:  " << std::is_trivially_destructible<P>::value;
}
```

> TC:  0
>   TCC: 1
>   TCv: 1
>    CC: 1
>    MC: 1
>   TCA: 0
>   TCvA:0
>    CA: 1
>    MA: 1
>   TD:  1

Evidently it isn't trivially copy assignable.<sup>1</sup>

The `pair` assignment operator is user-defined, so not trivial.

---

<sup>1</sup>I think that clang, gcc, and msvc are all wrong here, actually, but if it satisfied `std::_is_trivially_copy_assignable` it wouldn't help, because TriviallyCopyable requires that the copy constructor, if not deleted, is trivial, and not the TriviallyCopyAssignable trait.  Yeah, they're different.

> A copy/move assignment operator for class X is trivial **if it is not user-provided** and...

vs

> `is_assignable_v<T, const T&>` is true and the assignment, as defined by
>   `is_assignable`, is known to call no operation that is not trivial.

The operations called by `pair<double, double>`'s copy assignment operator are the assignments of individual doubles, which *are* trivial.

Unfortunately, the definition of *trivially copyable* relies on the first, which `pair` fails.

> A trivially copyable class is a class:
>
> - where each copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, and move assignment operator is either deleted or trivial,
> - that has at least one non-deleted copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator, and
> - that has a trivial, non-deleted destructor.

Comment: I understand that for tuple the case is complicated, but for pair I don't see why the copy assignment is not defaulted. Probably because assignment is templated wrt the source types and generates among other things a non-defaulted copy assignment. Sfinae should solve that and `pair<TC, TC>` can be TC as it should.

Comment: @alfC: `std::pair` has a user-defined copy assignment, which is already enough to break trivially copyability.

Comment: Yes, but why. There are sure ways to avoid having a user defined copy assignment.

Comment: @alfC: Related: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/PUZ9WUr2AOU

Comment: @alfC: Here's a discussion where it seems the only reason it's user-defined is for backward compatibility: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!msg/std-proposals/Zi2wriFMFvI/N1JlOE-FBQAJ

Comment: Ok, I think it is a defect of the implementation after all. Also, as a side note I could use is_trivially_destructible instead. I have a hard time imagining a trivially destructible class that is not memcopyable.

Comment: @alfC: Undefined behavior goes beyond "I'll take the chance of overwriting my memory"... if the compiler detects that your function causes undefined behavior, your code will no longer be optimization-stable.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to say that trivially destructible apparently was harder to break that trivially copyable. I think memcpy IS the optimization here. (btw, memcpy is just an example what I really want is to use binary streaming when possible).

Comment: Arguably the standard requires user-defined assignment operators for `tuple` in [tuple.tuple] and the same for `pair` in [pair.pair] because they are not defaulted at the site of the declaration even conditionally. Keep in mind that a method that is declared without definition, and defaulted later is considered user-defined (after all, the `default` could not be visible from all TUs). It would make sense to change it if all elements are TC and not references, and it shouldn't hurt any sane legacy code IMO, but at the moment it will be hard to argue that this is an implementation defect.

Comment: @Arne: Agreed, the operator is required to be user-defined by the current text of the Standard.  The implementation bug I see is in the implementation of the type trait `is_trivially_assignable`, because it doesn't reflect the rule given in the Standard (which is unfortunately different from the rule for a trivial assignment operator)

Comment: @BenVoigt, why do you mention `is_trivially_assignable`? what would be the bug in the trait? isn't also the trait implemented as a compiler hook? Do you mean that it is a bug in the compiler?

Comment: BTW, there is a case where everything works well: `std::complex`, `static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<std::complex<double>>{});`

Comment: @alfC: Yes, `std::complex` is trivially copyable (if the element type is), so is `std::array`.  They don't have the extra-special sauce that supports `tie` usage.

Answer (score 4):

This is only a partial answer to your question:

**Type traits don't necessarily mean what their name says literally.**

Specifically, let's take `std::is_trivially_copyable`. You were - rightly - surprised that a tuple of two double's is not trivially copyable. How could that be?!

Well, the [trait definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) says:

> If `T` is a `TriviallyCopyable` type, provides the member constant `value` equal `true`. For any other type, `value` is `false`.

and the [`TriviallyCopyable` concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable) has the following requirement in its definition:

> - Every copy constructor is trivial or deleted
> - Every move constructor is trivial or deleted
> - Every copy assignment operator is trivial or deleted
> - Every move assignment operator is trivial or deleted
> - At least one copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator is non-deleted
> - Trivial non-deleted destructor

Not quite what you would expect, right?

With all in mind, it's not necessarily the case that any of the standard library traits would combine to fit the exact requirements of "constructible by `memcpy()`'ing".

Comment: Got it, trivial means that it does nothing not that is does something simple. I guess the only hope is is_pod and/or is_agregate. Which is unlikely to work. I guess I will implement recursively some custom trait based on the conviction that tuples of memcopyable stuff should be memcopyable in it self.

Comment: @alfC: I think `is_pod` [is going away in C++20](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod).

Comment: Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225673/why-is-stdis-pod-deprecated-in-c20. It is not clear with what it is replaced with. I hope the change derives in some kind of more powerful trait that includes the near podness of tuples.

Comment: I am confused now, your like actually says "Objects of trivially-copyable types are the only C++ objects that may be safely copied with std::memcpy". I guess the problem is that it doesn't work the other way around; there are obvious types that can be memcpy'd and but `std::is_trivially_copyable` is false.

Comment: @alfC: I think the words there may need a bit of work; probably they mean trivially-copyable in the colloquial sense, not in "standardese".

Comment: @einpoklum: Nope, `TriviallyCopyable` is the condition the Standard puts on use of a type with `memcpy`.  The counter-intuitive thing is that `memcpy` can't be used with that pair, not any misbehavior in `std::is_trivially_copyable`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: In what sense can memcpy not be used with that pair? Also, in general, what you're saying can't be true, since one can artificially break `TriviallyCopyable` without actually changing anything about a class.

Comment: @einpoklum: In the sense that the Standard doesn't define the behavior of using `memcpy` on any type that isn't TriviallyCopyable.  "For any trivially copyable type T, if two pointers to T point to distinct T objects obj1 and obj2, where neither obj1 nor obj2 is a base-class subobject, if the underlying bytes making up obj1 are copied into obj2, obj2 shall subsequently hold the same value as obj1."

Comment: and "For any object (other than a base-class subobject) of trivially copyable type T, whether or not the object holds a valid value of type T, the underlying bytes making up the object can be copied into an array of char, unsigned char, or std::byte. If the content of that array is copied back into the object, the object shall subsequently hold its original value."   There's nothing else that defines the behavior of making a bytewise copy, and footnotes on those two rules call out `memcpy` as an example of this copy.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure which test you think `std::pair<double,double>` should fail.  TriviallyCopyable only restricts copy and move constructors, the "obscenely rich set" you mention are totally irrelevant.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I thought OP reported it fails. Anyway, will edit. About the non-definition in the standard - that's a bit puzzling, since if I take a `TriviallyCopyable` class, changed the default copy ctor into a custom copy ctor which does the same thing - you're saying the result of mencoy()ubg this undefibed

Comment: @einpoklum: It does fail, due to a user-defined assignment operator.  So I'm confused why you are blaming the constructor.  And yes, the Standard treats a user-provided constructor quite differently from a defaulted constructor that does the exact same thing.  The guarantee that memcpy will work does not apply if any of the special member functions related to copying -- copy and move constructors, copy and move assignment, and destruction -- are user-defined (as a specific case of "non-trivial").

Answer (score 4):

To try and answer your question: `std::memcpy()` does not have any direct requirements but it does have these stipulations:

> - Copies count bytes from the object pointed to by src to the object pointed to by dest. Both objects are reinterpreted as arrays of unsigned char.

- If the objects overlap, the behavior is undefined.
- If either dest or src is a null pointer, the behavior is undefined, even if count is zero.
- If the objects are not TriviallyCopyable, the behavior of memcpy is not specified and may be undefined.

---

Now to have the qualifications that an object is Trivially Copyable the following conditions or requirements must be met:

> - Every copy constructor is trivial or deleted

- Every move constructor is trivial or deleted
- Every copy assignment operator is trivial or deleted
- Every move assignment operator is trivial or deleted
- at least one copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator is non-deleted
- Trivial non-deleted destructor

> This implies that the class has no virtual functions or virtual base classes.

> Scalar types and arrays of TriviallyCopyable objects are TriviallyCopyable as well, as well as the const-qualified (but not volatile-qualified) versions of such types.

---

Which leads us to `std::is_trivially_copyable`

> If T is a TriviallyCopyable type, provides the member constant value equal true. For any other type, value is false.

The only trivially copyable types are scalar types, trivially copyable classes, and arrays of such types/classes (possibly const-qualified, but not volatile-qualified).

> 

The behavior is undefined if std::remove_all_extents_t is an incomplete type and not (possibly cv-qualified) void.

with this nice feature since c++17:

> Helper variable template
>
> ```
> template< class T >
> ```

```
inline constexpr bool is_trivially_copyable_v = is_trivially_copyable<T>::value;
```

---

And you would like to try and use a `type_trait` to use `std::tuple<>` with `std::memcpy()`.

But we need to ask ourselves if `std::tuple` is `Trivially Copyable` and why?

We can see the answer to that here: [Stack-Q/A: std::tuple Trivially Copyable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779985/why-cant-stdtupleint-be-trivially-copyable) and according to that answer; it is not because the standard does not require the copy/move assignment operators to be trivial.

---

So the answer that I would think that is valid would be this: No `std::tuple` is not Trivially Copyable but `std::memcpy()` doesn't require it to be but only states that if it isn't; it is UB. So can you use `std::tuple` with `std::memcpy`? I think so, but is it safe? That can vary and can produce UB.

So what can we do from here? Take a risk? Maybe. I found something else that is related but have not found anything out about it regarding if it is Trivially Copyable. It is not a `type_trait`, but it is something that might be able to be used in conjunction with `std::tuple` & `std::memcpy` and that is `std::tuple_element`. You might be able to use this to do the memcpy, but I'm not fully sure about it. I have searched to find out more about `std::tuple_element` to see if it is Trivially Copyable but haven't found much so all I can do is a test to see what Visual Studio 2017 says:

```
template<class... Args>
struct type_list {
    template<std::size_t N>
    using type = typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable<type_list<int, float, float>>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable<std::tuple<int, float, float>>::value << '\n';

    _getch(); // used to stop visual studio debugger from closing.
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

So it appears if we wrap `std::tuple_element` in a struct it is Trivially Copyable. Now the question is how do you integrate this with your `std::tuple` data sets to use them with `std::memcpy()` to be `type safe`. Not sure if we can since `std::tuple_element` will return the types of the elements within a `tuple`.

If we even tried to wrap a `tuple` in a struct as such:

```
template<class... Args>
struct wrapper {
    std::tuple<Args...> t;
};
```

And we can check it by:

```
{
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable< wrapper<int, float, float> >::value << std::endl;
}
```

It is still `false`. However we have seen were `std::tuple` was already used in the first struct and the struct returned `true`. This may be of some help to you, to ensure you can safely use `std::memcpy`, but I can not guarantee it. It is just that the compiler seems to agree with it. So this might be the closest thing to a `type_trait` that might work.

---

**NOTE:** - All the references about `memcpy`, `Trivially Copyable concepts`, `is_trivially_copyable`, `std::tuple` & `std::tuple_element` were taken from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) and their relevant pages.

Comment: I don't get it. Tuple_element is used to get the type of an index , it doesn't hold any value, that is why is trivial.

Comment: @alfC yeah I'm not familiar with it. I didn't know if it could be used.

Comment: @alfC I think I worded the end of my answer wrong; as the OP was looking for a `type_trait` and this might help with that part of his question.