# Can I safely memcpy a struct/class with copy constructor defined equivalently to the default copy constructor?

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, opencv3.0, memcpy

**Edit:** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29777728/2436175) seems to address perfectly my question.

---

Regarding [Which type trait would indicate that type is memcpy assignable? (tuple, pair)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120246/which-type-trait-would-indicate-that-type-is-memcpy-assignable-tuple-pair)

The answer is that `std::is_trivially_copyable` would be able to tell me if I can safely `memcpy` around my object.

Now consider:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
    int x;
    int y;
    A(const A& other) : x(other.x), y(other.y){}
};

struct B {
    int x;
    int y;
    B(const B& other) = default;
};

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable<A>::value << '\n'; //false
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable<B>::value << '\n'; //true
}
```

`A` and `B` are to all practical effect the same, however `A` is detected as not trivially copyable.

So, which risk am I would be taking in `memcpy`-ing such an object?

The use case: I would like to have a dynamic array (not `vector`, and which I would make grow with `realloc`) of `cv::Point` in opencv library, which probably because of C++98 compatibility doesn't use `default` to define the copy constructor.

Comment: If the type's copy constructor really does just copy the bytes, the compiler will know to optimize it to `memcpy` anyway. Don't sweat it.

Comment: @Brian See edit: my precise use case is an array of `cv::Point` where I would use a realloc (I understand the check on  `std::is_trivially_destructible` becomes superfluous when `std::is_trivially_copyable` is passed)

Comment: Why would you memcpy the objects when that is what the default copy constructor will do?

Comment: @NeilButterworth If I want to copy one array of `cv::Point` into another (assume I have good reasons not to use a `std::vector`)

Comment: @Antonio: I think Neil's point is that `std::copy` will implicitly invoke the default copy constructor for you, so why not just do that instead of testing the limits of defined behavior? Is `std::copy(&src[0], &src[len], &dst[0])` or `std::copy_n(&src[0], len, &dst[0])` somehow worse than `memcpy(&dst[0], &src[0], len * sizeof(src[0]))`?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Good point, but again this doesn't cover `realloc`!

Comment: Was about to write the exact same thing as the dupe. Really *really* thorough explanation there, so I stopped

Comment: Can't you use allocate the array with `new`?

Comment: `realloc` will copy the memory for you if it moves the allocation(!)

Comment: @WillCrawford And so? The point is that if the object is not trivially copiable, then we are invoking undefined behaviour. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777492/why-would-the-behavior-of-stdmemcpy-be-undefined-for-objects-that-are-not-triv/29777728#29777728).

Comment: Point being, we'd need a `renew` operator, I guess :) leaving it to manual handling is error-prone as well as tending to cause "undefined" behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The chief risk is that the optimizer outright removes the call to `memcpy`. That's a perfectly reasonable optimization: the fastest code is code which isn't called, and it's safe to assume code isn't called with incorrect parameters.

This also leads to the second risk: the optimizer may remove not just the `memcpy` call, but all code inevitably leading up to it. It may backtrack to a preceding `if` statement, observe which branch leads to the `memcpy`, and just remove that whole branch and the test condition too.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler sees you have a copy constructor and backs off. It doesn't care what is in it, though it would be good if this simple case where the assignments add nothing to the default was detected by the compiler.

In this particular case, you can get away with it, no real harm done.
On the other hand, you leave a maintenance nightmare for the next developer.
Can't you get rid of the constructor, or replace it with `=default`?

Also, I'm not sure memcpy would be significantly faster than a loop-unrolled and inlined chain of these simple constructor calls?

Answer (score -2):

You can memcpy the objects back and forth as much as you want. The binary representation and alignment requirements of the structs are the same.

If you really don't believe it, you can create static_asserts that check that the size and offsets are the same.

Comment: This is just incorrect

Comment: How is it incorrect in this particular example?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777492/why-would-the-behavior-of-stdmemcpy-be-undefined-for-objects-that-are-not-triv

Comment: The operation is only 'undefined' in so far as the language rules don't interpret what the constructor is doing. But any implementation that exists in reality is going to be fine.