# Why is it not possible to instantiate an atomic pair?

Tags: c++, std-pair, stdatomic

When compiling the following piece of code (gcc-4.8, `--std=c++11`):

```
#include <atomic>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdint>

struct X {
    std::atomic<std::pair<uint32_t, uint32_t>> A;
};
```

I get the following compilation error:

> ```
> /usr/local/include/c++/4.8.2/atomic:167:7: error: function
>  'std::atomic<_Tp>::atomic() [with _Tp = std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>]'
>  defaulted on its first declaration with an exception-specification that differs
>  from the implicit declaration 'constexpr std::atomic<std::pair<unsigned int, 
> unsigned int> >::atomic()'
> ```

With a more recent compiler (gcc-9 with `--std=c++17`), I get:

> ```
> In instantiation of 'struct std::atomic<std::pair<int, int> >':
>   error: static assertion failed: std::atomic requires a trivially copyable type
> static_assert(__is_trivially_copyable(_Tp),
> ```

demos:

- https://godbolt.org/z/ozhWuq
- https://godbolt.org/z/tFKG5f

I can't figure out the reason why; can anyone help me please?

Comment: give the command line used to compile as well, this data is insufficient

Comment: @bartop In fact, I'm using a compile tool just like Bazel of Google, so the command line is too long and contains too much information which is not related to this problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`std::atomic<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) requires `T` to be [*TriviallyCopyable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable).

You cannot define an `std::atomic<std::pair<...>>` because `std::pair` is not trivially copiable. For more information about that, read [Why can't std::tuple be trivially copyable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38780211/5470596).

As a workaround, you can define your own simplified trivially copiable pair:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>

struct X
{
    using pair = struct { std::uint32_t first; std::uint32_t second; };
    std::atomic<pair> A;
};
```

demo: https://godbolt.org/z/epPvOr

Answer (score -1):

The following will provide you with the right kind of atomic pair:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::pair<std::atomic<int>, std::atomic<int>> counterPair;
  counterPair.first.store(0);
  counterPair.second.store(0);
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
 
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&counterPair, i]() {
      for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        if((i + j) % 2 == 1) {
          counterPair.first++;
        } else {
          counterPair.second++;
        }
      }
    }));
  }

  for(auto& thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
  }

  std::cout << counterPair.first.load() << ", " << counterPair.second.load() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

demo: https://godbolt.org/z/T6f3s9xqd

Comment: That's only the "right kind" if you just need two separately-atomic objects, and don't need them to go together in a single atomic snapshot of both of them.

Comment: That's not an atomic pair, but a pair of atomics. It doesn't guarantee that the two elements of the pair are only modified atomically together so that they are always in a consistent state.